# Error installing packages in R after messing with "pahts"

Tags: r, macos

I was trying to install the rattle package in R and got this error message saying

```
configure: error: GTK version 2.8.0 required
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘RGtk2’
```

Then I tried to fix the RGtk2 problem using this guide

http://marcoghislanzoni.com/blog/2014/08/29/solved-installing-rattle-r-3-1-mac-os-x-10-9/

I tried this code in the Mac OS terminal (but this is above my understanding) :

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
sudo port selfupdate
sudo port install pkgconfig
export PATH=/opt/pkgconfig/bin:$PATH
sudo port install gtk2 +x11
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/opt/local/lib/pkgconfig
```

It gave me this answer

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
ad-mac0630:~ caruc35$ sudo port selfupdate
Password:
Sorry, try again.
Password:
```

And locked down.

I also installed XCode command line tools from Apple and tried some stuff from the guide above. It didnt get the rattle package to work so I erased it.

After messing with this the rattle package does still not work and R seems not to work as it did before. For example i can´t load the xlsx package getting this error message:

```
    Loading required package: rJava
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: dyn.load(file, DLLpath = DLLpath, ...)
  error: unable to load shared object '/Users/caruc35/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so':
  dlopen(/Users/caruc35/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so, 6): Library not loaded: @rpath/libjvm.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/caruc35/Library/R/3.4/library/rJava/libs/rJava.so
  Reason: image not found
Error: package ‘rJava’ could not be loaded
```

Did I mess up when trying to change PATH? Is there a way to reset everything back to normal?

I have tried reinstalling R but the same problems still occurs.

Comment: Do you have macports installed? Anyway, sudo requires your password. I'm guessing you ran the next line instead?

Comment: I did not proceed after running the code because I had not a clue what I was doing… Do you think me fiddling around with this had any impact on the trouble with loading other packages in R?